# How to parse comment from XML with XMLEventReader?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing an incoming XML file with an XMLInputFactory like the following. How do I get the text out of an XML comment? I know how to detect it, but, not get the text out

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(incomingFile);
XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(fis);


while (eventReader.hasNext())
{
   XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

   if (event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.COMMENT)
   {
       // Right here, how do I get the comment?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [javax.xml.stream.events.Comment.getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/events/Comment.html#getText()) to get the string data of a comment, or the empty string if it doesn't exist:

```
((javax.xml.stream.events.Comment) event).getText()
```